# List few JQuery objects in one selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

It's not critical, just want to make my code perfect.
So, we have:

```
var $a = $('div#first-very-long-selector');
var $b = $('div#second-very-long-selector');

// I can make this:
$a.fadeOut(10000);
$b.fadeOut(10000);

// or this:
$('div#first-very-long-selector,div#second-very-long-selector').fadeOut(10000);

// we can put object to selector, like:
$($a).fadeOut(10000);
$($b).fadeOut(10000);

// BUT this way doesn't work:
$($a,$b).fadeOut(10000);

// put them to array doesn't work too:
$([$a,$b]).fadeOut(10000);

// use .map doesn't help:
[$a,$b].map($.fadeOut);
```

We all know that put objects to variable is better for performance, and also usually it makes code shorter. But how to use few this variables together for same action?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selectors can be aimed at ID's or Classes. Read here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Also - you don't need to set a javascript variable using $. you can do so as such

```
var CoolVariable = $('#whateverdiviwant');
```

For instance, say you wanted to fade out just one element. You would target that specific ID.

But if you wanted to target all the elements you would target the class. You would do this if you were planning on running the same function on multiple elements.

I've made a little demo for you to try out, demonstrating what I mentioned above & including setting elements to variables.

```js
var a = $('#one'),
    b = $('#two'),
    c = $('.div-choice');

$('#fadeA').click(function() {
   a.fadeOut(1000);
});

$('#fadeB').click(function() {
   b.fadeOut(1000);
});

$('#fadeAll').click(function() {
   c.fadeOut(1000);
});

$('#revert').click(function() {
   c.fadeIn(1000);
});
```

```css
#one {
  background-color: blue;
}

#two {
  background-color: red;
}

.div-choice {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" class="div-choice">A</div>
<div id="two" class="div-choice">B</div>
<button id="fadeA">Fade A</button>
<button id="fadeB">Fade B</button>
<button id="fadeAll">Fade All</button>
<button id="revert">Bring back</button>
```

**EDIT**

Hopefully I'm not wasting you're time reading this - but I believe you would have to store the variables as an array, then loop through that array calling the function for each item in the array. This is probably the only way ***( that I know of )*** to achieve what you're looking for.

Like so:

```
var g       = [ a, b ],
    gLength = g.length;

$('#someDiv').click(function() {
   for ( i = 0; i < gLength; i++ ) {
     g[i].fadeOut(1000);
   }
});
```

See this codepen with my updates. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNyjMr

Comment: Thanks for answer! I know how it works, maybe I explained my question bad.
For example this code "$($a).fadeOut(5000);" will work too, so there could be not only selectors, also objects. But not few objects :(

Answer (score 0):

Is the markup such that you could just iterate through all of the child elements and attach your needed functions using `this`?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vyWoEr

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
</div>

<script>
$('#wrapper').children('div').each(function () {
  $(this).click(function(e) {
    alert('I can do stuff to ' + $(this).text())
  })
});
</script>
```